# New version of Rails asking for old version of Railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting ready to start on a new Ruby on Rails project. On my mac, I've installed the latest version of Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

and the latest version of gem:

```
$ gem -v
2.2.2
```

and seemingly successfully installed Rails 4.0.4. However, when I test rails, I get the following error:

```
$ rails -v
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 3.2.14) - did find: [railties-4.0.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

If I run rails as superuser, it works fine:

```
$ sudo rails -v
Rails 4.0.4
```

It seems to be the same version, no matter how I run it:

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails

$ sudo which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
```

The PATH is the same whether I run with sudo or not. Something in the environment is different, I guess, but what?

I could just use sudo whenever I need to run rails, but I'd like to understand the problem and fix it if I can.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I discovered that if I run sh instead of bash, the problem disappears. At the moment, I've reconfigured Terminal to run sh on startup and this solves my immediate problem, but would still like to figure out what's wrong in the bash environment.

Comment: The error message indicates you also have another version of Ruby installed (2.1.0). Are you using RVM or rbenv?

Comment: I have tried both, but think they are both totally uninstalled. I'll check to make sure... Yes, both are removed from system. Current Ruby/gem is installed from source.

Comment: Is there anything in your `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock` that is set to that version?

Comment: do I have a Gemfile if I haven't created a project?

Comment: The thing is RVM and rbenv may be uninstalled, but you seem to have remains of a previous Ruby installation. I would first try `gem pristine rails`, then if it doesn't work you might want to remove all traces of Ruby from your system by doing a `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby && sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ruby && sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ruby && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/irb && sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/irb && sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gem && sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/gem`

Comment: I have had several versions of Ruby and Rails... Think you are probably right. I wish I could figure out what is different in the environments, that would probably help pinpoint the problem. Will start hunting for old rubies...